# Display the page title dynamically

Tags: codeigniter

I've an existing CodeIgniter Application with lot of pages where all the page titles( h1 tag ) are hard coded in the views. Now **I'm looking to populate the titles dynamically from the below table structure with as much less effort as possible**.

```
CREATE TABLE `page_title` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `page_no` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `page_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` tinytext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `page_title`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

Need suggestion on how to display the title with a good approach. I was thinking to create a common model and call the model in the view with page_id pass to get the page_no and page_title for that id.

Comment: you are calling the view in some controller, right? there is the right place to call the model

Comment: @Vickel right, But in that case I've make changes in all the controllers and views in the application to display the title. There are lot of pages in the application, so it's tedious job. Any other way to make it quick?

Comment: FYI, application has common views like header, sidebar, footer. Any chance we can use these to achieve it?